# Set JSON response as first item in Spinner

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask, android-spinner

I have my AsyncTask that performs some Google API request and parses a JSON which will return a String that I need to set as the first item in my spinner from my main activity. Here is my AsyncTask.

```
public class CountyData extends AsyncTask<Object, String, String> {
String geoData;
String url;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
    try {
        Log.d("GetGeoData", "doInBackground entered");
        url = (String) params[0];
        DownloadUrl downloadUrl = new DownloadUrl();
        geoData = downloadUrl.readUrl(url);
        Log.d("GeoData", geoData);
        Log.d("GeoReadTask", "doInBackground Exit");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("GeoReadTask", e.toString());
    }
    return geoData;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Log.d("GeoReadTask", "onPostExecute Entered");
    String geoCounty = null;
    DataParser dataParser = new DataParser();
    geoCounty =  dataParser.parse(result); //I need to set this String as the first item in my spinner
    Log.d("GooglePlacesReadTask", "onPostExecute Exit");
}
```

}

The geoCounty String is the String which I need to return to my main activity and set as the first item in spinner. My main activity is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private Spinner spinner1;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

this.spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, counties);
        this.spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

How can I return my String from onPostExecute and set it as the first item in my spinner ? Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Just initialize the spinner content in the `onPostExecute`

Comment: You can create a custom adapter and add the string inside `onPostExecute` and notify adapter data change

Comment: There isn't a way to send it to my main activity ?

Comment: @Pop make use to **Interface** to send the data to `MainActivity` from `CountyData#onPostExecute ()`

Comment: @android_hub could you give me some guidance on how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions to this problem..

**1. Interfaces**

In Android to pass data from any other class Interfaces are used.
You can send the data from your asynctask's onPostExectute directly to MainActivity and update the spinner value. For that one learn the interfaces in Android.

**2. Same class Code**

Writting the asynctask in same activity class in which view components to be modified / updated is the another solution.
you can directly modify the spinner object in onPostExecute if the asynctask is the subclass of that activity. Use progressDialogs to avoid UI glithching.

Answer (score 0):

Create an **Interface** to communicate with your `MainActivity`

```
public class CountyData extends AsyncTask<Object, String, String> {

    private OnDownloadCompleteListener mListener;

    CountyData(OnDownloadCompleteListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
        ...
        ...
        return geoData;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        ...
        ...
        mListener.onDownloadComplete(s);
    }

    public interface OnDownloadCompleteListener {
        void onDownloadComplete(String result);
    }
}
```

Implement the interface in you `MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CountryData.OnDownloadCompleteListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_download);

        ...
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onDownloadComplete(String result) {
       // populate the spinner adapter item here 
    }
}
```

Comment: it gives a NullPointerException when I call my method in onPostExecute. Here :  mListener.onDownloadComplete(s);

Comment: How are you calling **CountryData** in your activity? You need to initialise listener

Comment: I do this in my onCreate method:  CountyData getcounty = new CountyData();
            getcounty.execute(data);

Comment: Do I have to do something else?

Comment: you need to use **new CountyData(OnDownloadCompleteListener listener)** constructor to initialise the listener

Comment: I added this as a field in my CountyData: private Object listener; and I changed it to this: CountyData getcounty = new CountyData((CountyData.OnDownloadCompleteListener) listener);
            getcounty.execute(data);

Comment: I still get NullPointer